# How to generate all possible lang fields for a modded Minecraft pack?

Tags: minecraft-modding

I want to translate a modpack [Tekkit2](https://www.technicpack.net/modpack/tekkit-2.1935271) in Minecraft. According to [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Creating_a_resource_pack) one has to create a resource pack and map identifier-translation pairs to a json file. However in order for the translation to be whole, I would have to know the identifiers of modded items, which I couldn't find on any site. Is it possible to generate a list of keys and their default values?

Answer (score 0):

*Some* mods provide their identifiers in their .jar file so the best course is to make a script that goes trough the mods and find the appropriate lang file and extract the keys.